# how to write a cypher statement to find out first match node i want

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes like this:

```
 (a {export:true})->(b {export:false})->(c {export:false})->
 .....some other nodes with export field is false->
 (d {export:true})->(e {export:true})
```

Now I only want to find out a and d, which have a relationship

```
(a {export:true})-->(b {expor:true})
```

I write some cypher statements, but can not work, they will return a->d and a->e. do somebody knows how to write a cypher statement that can work like I want?

thanks you

Comment: please post the query you tried

Comment: Are you trying to write a query that finds which nodes are connected where exports: true, connected through items where exports:false?

Comment: thanks, guys, my problem resolved by cybersam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer A

The following query returns all connected `export:true` node pairs separated by 0 or more nodes that all contain `export:false`.

```
MATCH p=(a { export:true })-[*]->(b { export:true })
WHERE
  LENGTH(p) = 1 OR
  ALL (x IN NODES(p)[1..LENGTH(p)-1] WHERE NOT x.export)
RETURN a, b;
```

Note: `LENGTH(p)` returns the number of relationships in path `p`.

## Answer B

`Answer A` can actually be simplified by removing the `LENGTH(p) = 1` test:

```
MATCH p=(a { export:true })-[*]->(b { export:true })
WHERE ALL (x IN NODES(p)[1..LENGTH(p)-1] WHERE NOT x.export)
RETURN a, b;
```

But why this simplified query also works requires more of an explanation. If `LENGTH(p)` is 1, then:

1. `NODES(p)[1..0]` results in `[]`, and
2. `ALL(x IN [] WHERE ...)` results in `true` (no matter what `...` is).

Comment: thanks, cybersam. your answer is great help  for me.